# Change the URL where your github-pages are hosted

Tags: github, github-pages

My github pages are currently hosted on:

```
https://<my_organisation_name>.github.io/<my_repo_name>/
```

I actually would like to either have a redirect from

```
https://<my_organisation_name>.github.io/
```

to

```
  https://<my_organisation_name>.github.io/<my_repo_name>/
```

**OR**

to have

`https://<my_organisation_name>.github.io/<my_repo_name>/`

hosted at

`https://<my_organisation_name>.github.io/`

Any idea how to do it ?